# Passing multiple object values between controllers using a service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two controllers and setup a service to hold the data:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.factory('Data', function() {
    return { message: "This is a message from a service", Type: "This is a type from a service" }
});


function FirstCtrl($scope, Data) {
    $scope.data = Data;
}

function SecondCtrl($scope, Data) {
    $scope.data = Data;
}
```

In my HTML, I have inputs to bind these values:

```
    <div ng-controller="FirstCtrl">
      <input type="text" ng-model="data.message">
      <h1>{{ data.message }}</h1>
    </div>

    <div ng-controller="SecondCtrl">
      <input type="text" ng-model="data.type">
      <h1>{{ data.type }}</h1>
    </div>
```

However, all im getting back from the service is my `data.message` and nothing for `data.type`.

Why is this?

Comment: it should be data.Type - only a typo?

Answer (score 0):

It is a simple type error. The Factory returns a Data object with 'Type' as a key. In your HTML you have used 'type' as the key instead of 'Type'.